# Does RAZL can compare different versions of site core database

Tags: sitecore

Does RAZL can compare Sitecore 6.5 (core,master,web) databases with Sitecore8.1(core,master,web) databases.

Or it can compare only same versions of Sitecore.

I need to use this for a migration from Sitecore 6.5 to Sitecore 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can.

But keep in mind that using RAZL is not a recommended practice for Sitecore upgrades. Why? There are plenty of reasons. Some of them can be found in this article:

[The Truth About Sitecore Upgrades](http://www.seanholmesby.com/the-truth-about-sitecore-upgrades/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree.

I have used RAZL in the past for moving the content. You can use this to move content from one Sitecore instance to another one even on different versions, but I would not recommend it using for Sitecore migration because you may move the content without properly moving dependencies first. This tool is good if you want to move very heavy content without too much of definition changes or you can use RAZL for comparison.